# How to determine if a set of vectors can be written as a span?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $A =\{ (a,b)∈\Bbb{R}^2 : a = 0$ or $b = 0\}$

Specifically, I'm wondering if this set can be written as a span, if so, how? and if not, are there rules or ways to tell if something can be written as a span?

Comment: If something is a span then it is a vector space. You should check that this is not a vector space since it isn’t closed under linear combinations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a span, it must be a vector space. One has $(1,0) \in A$ and $(0,1) \in A$, but $(1,0)+(0,1) = (1,1) \notin A$, so $A$ is not a vector space, thus not a span.

Comment: do you mean (1,0) in A and (0,1) in B? (1,0) + (1,0) = (2,0) doesn't it?

Comment: sorry, it was a typo, should be good now

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I'll check if it obeys the rules of a vector space next time.